# how to replace inital digits of ssn with '*' while using mask of jquery

Tags: jquery, html

how to replace inital digits of ssn with '*' while using mask of jquery

for example:
123-45-6789
will be inserted as ***-**-6789
,but when we fetch the value we should get 123456789

Answer (score 3):

Given HTML as follows:

```
<form id="ssn_form">
    <input name="ssn" id="ssn" type="text">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>​
```

You can store the SSN in a data attribute on blur and mask the value.  Then on form submit you can repopulate the value into the input right before submitting the form:

```
var retrieveValue = function(ev){
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.data('value');

        if (val) {
            $this.val(val);
        }
    },
    hideValue = function(ev){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.data('value', $this.val());
        $this.val($this.val().replace(/^\d{5}/, '*****'));
    };

$('#ssn').focus(retrieveValue);

$('#ssn').blur(hideValue);

$('#ssn_form').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    retrieveValue.call($('#ssn')[0], ev);
    $(this).submit();
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nKa8z/)

Comment: Submit function will cause a recursive loop. Instead just adding this will do the trick $('#ssn_form').submit(function(ev){
    retrieveValue.call($('#ssn')[0], ev);
    
});

Answer (score 0):

Without any code supply i think this is the best you can try with :)

INPUT -  `123-45-6789`

OUTPUT-  `***-**-6789`

Check this --

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function mask(f){
tel='';
var val =f.value.split('');
for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
if(i<3){val[i]='*'}
if(i<6 && i>3 ){val[i]='*'}
tel=tel+val[i]
}
f.value=tel;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input name="phone" type="text" onblur="mask(this)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But After submitting we will lose the real value right so How to prevent that?

Comment: @Sanshayan you can always store the value in another variable